# Chrome fails to clear the thumbnails

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome

I am using Google chrome version 21.0.1180.89 (on Ubuntu 12.04) and when I clear the browsing data it fails to clear the [thumbnails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qP4pz.png) (the most visited ones that show up on a new tab page).

I deleted "Top Sites" and "Top Sites-journal" (under `~/.config/google-chrome/Default` path) but this did not clear out the thumbnails.

I am not even sure whether chrome actually counts the visit number on pages correctly or not anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [known bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=143567&can=5&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary) in the current version of Chrome.